# jar dependencies and beans.xml CDI Interceptors

Tags: jar, cdi, interceptor, java-ee-7

I have a small maven project made of 4 modules: ear, war, ejb-jar, common-jar. Both war and ejb-jar depend on common-jar. I've created an interceptor and added its annotation to one class in war and another in ejb-jar. I've tried creating it in several places:
a) interceptor in war, the annotated class in ejb-jar cant see it and app deployment fails
b) interceptor in ejb-jar, the annotated class in ejb-jar is intercepted but the annotated class in war is ignored
c) interceptor in common-jar, with beans.xml inside META-INF folder inside the jar. Interceptor is not found during deployment and no annotated class is intercepted

Ideally, the third case seems the right one. I can leave the interceptor classes in common-jar but the interceptor class only applies when bean.xml is inside ejb-jar/META-INF (it seems the only case where bean.xml is processed and the interceptor is applied to annotated classes). I'm using Java EE 7

Thanks

Comment: already asked in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051069/cdi-using-interceptors-across-different-modules-bean-archives

Comment: In my case it could be related to the following TomEE issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OWB-472?jql=text%20~%20"interceptor%20war"

Comment: Issue opened in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMEE-3790?filter=-2